# Error 404 Not Found trying to retrieve file content from Google Drive using http get

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I am trying to retrieve the content of a Google Drive file using HTTP get request in a Android app.  I've already authenticated myself and got the token, got the file metadata below (just replaced "sensitive info" with <"sensitive info">):

```
    {
    "kind": "drive#file",
    "id": ""myFileId"",
    "etag": ""this_etag"",
    "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/"myFileId"",
    "alternateLink": "https://docs.google.com/file/d/"myFileId"/edit",
    "thumbnailLink": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/thumbnailCode",
    "permissionsLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/"myFileId"/permissions",
    "title": "filename.txt",
    "mimeType": "text/plain",
    "labels": {
     "starred": false,
     "hidden": false,
     "trashed": false,
     "restricted": false,
     "viewed": true
    },
    "createdDate": "2012-07-13T17:53:29.589Z",
    "modifiedDate": "2012-07-13T18:58:36.729Z",
    "modifiedByMeDate": "2012-07-13T17:53:29.584Z",
    "lastViewedByMeDate": "2012-07-19T20:40:03.823Z",
    "parents": [
     {
      "kind": "drive#parentReference",
      "id": "",
      "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/"myFileId"/parents/"id"",
      "parentLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/"id"",
      "isRoot": true
     }
    ],
    "downloadUrl": "https://doc-0k-28-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/"bigCode"/"anotherBigCode"/"moreNumbers"/"moreNumbers"/"moreNumbers"/"myFileId"?h="moreNumbers"&e=download&gd=true",
    "userPermission": {
     "kind": "drive#permission",
     "etag": ""this_etag"",
     "id": "current",
     "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/"myFileId"/permissions/current",
     "role": "owner",
     "type": "user"
    },
    "originalFilename": "zzzz.txt",
    "fileExtension": "txt",
    "md5Checksum": "da22f14e635aa54e97e0e09b5d03a485",
    "fileSize": "51",
    "quotaBytesUsed": "51",
    "ownerNames": [
     "Emerson.yt"
    ],
    "lastModifyingUserName": "Emerson.yt",
    "editable": true,
    "writersCanShare": true
    }
```

When I try to get the contents using downloadUrl returned in the metadata it gives the error

```
"W/System.err(612): com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 404 Not Found"
```

The relevant java code I'm using:

```
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();

// prefs is a SharedPreferences instance 
// acquired throught PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
CredentialStore credentialStore = new SharedPreferencesCredentialStore(prefs);
TokenResponse accessTokenResponse = credentialStore.read();

Builder bldr = new Builder();
bldr.setTransport(transport);
bldr.setJsonFactory(jsonFactory);
bldr.setClientSecrets(myGoogleApiClientId, myGoogleApiClientSecret);

GoogleCredential accessProtectedResource = bldr.build();
accessProtectedResource.setAccessToken(accessTokenResponse.getAccessToken());
accessProtectedResource.setExpiresInSeconds(accessTokenResponse.getExpiresInSeconds());
accessProtectedResource.setRefreshToken(accessTokenResponse.getRefreshToken());

// HTTP_TRANSPORT is an instance of NetHttpTransport
HttpRequestFactory httpReqFactory = HTTP_TRANSPORT.createRequestFactory(accessProtectedResource);

GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/"myFileId"");
HttpRequest httpReq = httpReqFactory.buildGetRequest(url);
HttpResponse httpResp = httpReq.execute();
String resp = httpResp.parseAsString();
// just convert json string into java attributes of FileResourceMetadata class
FileResourceMetadata frm = new FileResourceMetadata(resp); 
String downloadURL = frm.downloadUrl; 
url = new GenericUrl(downloadURL); 
httpReq = httpReqFactory.buildGetRequest(url);
httpResp = httpReq.execute();
```

What's wrong?

Thanks, Emerson.

Comment: 404 is resource not found. Most probably it is something with url is not correct. Try to access same url in browser and see you are getting correct data or not.

Comment: what is the value of myFileId - you seem to have a hardcoded String in line 1 of the java you've given.

Comment: Yes 404 is resource not found, but I'm using the exact downloadUrl that comes in the meta data of the file, so I think it's correct.

Comment: myFileId is the file id of my file in Google Drive. I got it in File/Share. I also think it's correct because when I use it to retrive the meta data it returns the correct information. For instance: "originalFilename": "zzzz.txt", "fileSize": "51"

Comment: When I try to use the downloadUrl in browser (Opera) it returns: "The server requested a login authentication method that is not supported.
Check that the address is spelled correctly, or try searching for the site."  If I remove the last part of the url "&gd=true" it opens the download dialog and the file is downloaded normally.  If I use the downloadUrl without "&gd=true" in my android app, it returns Error 501 - Not implemented.

Comment: By the way. The downloadUrl in the meta data has the format: https://doc-0k-28-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/xxxxx/yyyyy/12345/12345/12345/abc12345?h=12345&e=download&gd=true

Comment: Just in case since you seem to be using lots of custom code: How do you authorize the request with the access token? Do you use the Authorization header or the access_token URL parameter? Currently the later is **not** supported.

Comment: Hi @Nivco I put the access token in the factory I use to create the http request. Am i missing something???

Comment: I've put the authorization token in the head with same results (404 - Not Found). `headers = httpReq.getHeaders();
 headers.setAuthorization(accessTokenResponse.getAccessToken());`.

Comment: That's good then :) the facory shold use teh Authorizarion header automatically. It's only if ou were creating the HTTP request yourself that you might have used the URL parameter to do so.

Comment: You code seem correct (thought I'm only very confortable with Java). One of the way I could see a 404 happening in that case is if you are authenticating with a different user that the one owning/have read access to the file.but it;s strage because if you read the metadata successfully then it should be all right... :/

Comment: Hi @Nivco, as I put before, if I use the downloadUrl from the metadata in a browser (removing the last part of it: "&gd=true") it works, it opens the download file dialog and downloads the file.

Comment: It seems to be related to this other StackOverflow [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11526699/1106381).

Comment: Hi @Alain what's this "?key=" parameter you refer to in that question? The downloadUrl doesn't have it. I'm already using `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` scope.