# How to initialize a Drive object in Android to perform requests to Google Drive?

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Open and Save files to/from Google Drive SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164024/android-open-and-save-files-to-from-google-drive-sdk)

I'm attempting to upload and download files from Google Drive in my android application.

I was able to obtain an authorization token string for the user's Google account using `AccountManager.getAuthToken()`.

Now, I don't know how to use that token to initialize the Drive object to start sending requests to Google Drive. I used the following code from an example in Google Drive scarce documentation, but it doesn't work. Apparently, the call succeeds, but when I try to upload a file, it just hangs up until Android tells me that the App is not responding.

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(authToken);
HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
Drive drive = null;

drive = Drive.builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory)
    .setApplicationName(APP_NAME)
    .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential)
    .setJsonHttpRequestInitializer(new GoogleKeyInitializer(API_KEY))
    .build();
```

To upload a certain file I do the following:

```
try
{
    // local file
    java.io.File fileLocal = new java.io.File(FILE_NAME);

    // remote file

    File remoteFile = new File();
    remoteFile.setTitle(fileLocal.getName());
    remoteFile.setDescription("Text File");
    remoteFile.setMimeType("text/plain");

    // load the content of the local file into the remote content
    FileContent remoteFileContent = new FileContent("text/plain", fileLocal);

    // upload the file into Google Drive
    File resultFile = drive.files().insert(remoteFile, remoteFileContent).execute();

    lblStatus.setText("Upload successful with file ID: " + resultFile.getId());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // error handling
    ...
}
```

I've read the Google API documents and they are a mess, and the classes don't have a proper documentation. The samples they give are quite messy.

Any idea why is the app not responding? What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue a few weeks ago. Have a look over here, where I wrote a pretty extensive explanation of how to make Google Drive mostly work on Android. (I say mostly because file downloads don't seem to be properly authorized...)

[Android Open and Save files to/from Google Drive SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164024/android-open-and-save-files-to-from-google-drive-sdk)