# How to keep data of an Android app in sync across multiple devices?

Tags: android, synchronization

My Android application, like almost every other app, stores its information (some private data of the users) in a local sqlite database. Now I got a tablet and I wondered if there is a convenient way to sync the data across multiple devices and keep it up to date automatically. Most other apps seem to use their own server for which you have to create an account.

The chapter of the Android developer pages called [Syncing to the Cloud](https://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/index.html) lists two solutions: Backup API and Cloud Messaging. But it seems that neither of those provides what I am searching for. While the [Backup API](https://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/backupapi.html) is used only for backup/restore of devices and not for synchronisation, the [Cloud Messages Service](https://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/gcm.html) requires a running application server on my side.

I do not want my users to create an account. Also I do not want to store their private data on my servers. Until now, my app does not even need the "Internet Connection" permission and if possible I want it to stay that way.

So my question is: Is there any cloud service provided by Google to keep app data in sync?

Comment: What was your solution to that problem? - I am having pretty much similiar requirements.

Comment: Until now there has been no solution. :(

Answer (score 2):

I believe Googles [App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/) is what you are looking for, Its not free but the pricing isnt bad

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use DropBox? i use it to share pictures beetwen android devices. Most important ... it is free ;)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you said you didn't want to many permissions, this solution goes against that. If you do not want to use your own server, your best bet would be to use the Drive API in order to back data to a user's drive account. If you are signed in to a google account on multiple devices, then is your best bet.

You should check out this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164024/android-open-and-save-files-to-from-google-drive-sdk) in order to get started and upload files to Drive.