# Android Drive Api getting 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I worked long and hard trying to integrate Google Drive in android application. But that's a trap - Google as always surprised - in a bad sense. It all started with the fact that I relied on the instructions ([first](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android), [first](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-java)) from Google. I fulfilled all the conditions - created OAuth 2.0, created a key for the application, the application reg., imported libraries ... generally did everything they asked and 100 times rechecked. But as expected did not work - in the first case is made all the example, I received a **"403 Forbidden Access Not Configured"**, the second one can not be implemented, because that Google has not issued a secret key. Throughout the week, I was looking for alternative solutions to this problem - a lot of examination of information, a lot of effort and time spent - but the result is 0. Glimmer of hope came through general questions [ArtOfWarfare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164024/android-open-and-save-files-to-from-google-drive-sdk). But the code that he proposed, and which allegedly he works, I do not work - I allow the application to use the account, followed by whose connection fails because of "communication error with Google", repeated attempts yield the same result. As a result, I drew "their" code just to try to communicate with the drive. Since I'm writing here - hence it does not work. Code shown below returns a **"400 Bad Request Invalid Upload Request",
"**. Do you have any ideas on how to solve this problem with authorization, or are there other ways of successful login? I'll be glad constructive conversation.

```
package com.example.hiv;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback;
import android.accounts.AccountManagerFuture;
import android.accounts.OperationCanceledException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.GoogleKeyInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;

public class ActivityStart extends Activity {

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_activity_start);
    String AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";
    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
    accountManager.invalidateAuthToken(accountManager.getAccounts()[0].type, null);
    accountManager.getAuthToken( accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google")[0], AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, null, this,
            new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {

                public void run(final AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
                    try {
                        String authToken = future.getResult().getString(
                                AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);

                            final HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
                            final JsonFactory jsonFactory = new GsonFactory();
                            GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential();
                            credential.setAccessToken(authToken);
                            final Drive drive = new Drive.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                                    .setApplicationName("HIV")
                                    .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleKeyInitializer("*****yDaPx1EtTHpMMMULzYlxjc3xdwsf******"))
                                    .build();

                            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                  try {
                                    final com.google.api.services.drive.model.File body = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
                                    body.setTitle("My Test File");
                                    body.setDescription("A Test File");
                                    body.setMimeType("text/plain");

                                    java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File("data/data/com.example.hiv/document.txt");
                                    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/plain", fileContent);

                                    com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file = drive.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();

                                  } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                  } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                  }
                                }
                              });
                              t.start(); 

                    } catch (OperationCanceledException exception) {
                        // TODO
                    } catch (Exception exception) {
                        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), exception.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }, null);       
  } 
}
```

Comment: solved: I'm trying to send a file whose size is 0 kB.

Comment: Then please answer or close this question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solved**: I'm trying to send a file whose size is 0 kB.