# How to upload a file to Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

So im trying to upload a text file to my google drive from an android app I am creating. I learned how to upload a picture from the Google tutorial. Also, I will be using the strings from my app in the text file. Potentially, I want to make it a spreadsheet.  Any help?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Read [Quick Start](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android) on Google Android site.

When you are done with all the authentication process, go for [How to upload file to Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads).

**Edit**

Reference Links

- https://code.google.com/p/google-drive-sdk-samples/
- [Android Open and Save files to/from Google Drive SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164024/android-open-and-save-files-to-from-google-drive-sdk)
- http://mavenrepo.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/com/google/apis/google-api-services-drive/v2-rev9-1.8.0-beta/

Comment: I tried reading the "How to upload file to Google Drive" but don't quite get it. It is a little confusing. I am new to Java and Android app.

Comment: which problem you are facing? Have you run that sample?

Comment: Problem is that I don't know of I should write a new class? or add the code to my main activity. Furthermore, can I just write in "https:" in java?

Comment: There are classes available to send HTTP request. Read http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNetworking/article.html.

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/49297056/1201441, there describe upload file in google drive. you can upload any type of file just change file_path and respected Mime type..

Answer (score 1):

I spent so much time for that... In my opinion documentation is ..... not so great.

**This is how it should be done with REST API v3. MULTIPART UPLOAD example**

> **1. STEP ONE - Create JSON with METADATA**

For example:

```
data class RetrofitMetadataPart(
    val parents: List<String>, //directories
    val name: String //file name
)
```

and now create a JSON (I used moshi for this)

```
val jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter<RetrofitMetadataPart>(RetrofitMetadataPart::class.java)

val metadataJSON = jsonAdapter.toJson(
    RetrofitMetadataPart(
        parents = listOf("yourFolderId"), 
        name = localFile.name
    )
)
```

of course you can create this metadata with different parameters,values, and of course in your preferred way.
Full list of metadata parameters you have here:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create

> **2. STEP TWO - Create Multipart with METADATA**

We create first part of our request with proper Header

```
val metadataPart = MultipartBody.Part.create(
    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), metadataJSON)
)
```

> **3. STEP THREE - Create Multipart with your FILE**

Create second part of our request with file

```
val multimediaPart = MultipartBody.Part.create(
    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), localFile)
)
```

> **4. STEP FOUR - call request**

```
googleDriveApi.uploadFileMultipart(
    metadataPart,
    multimediaPart
)
```

and this invoke

```
@Multipart
@POST("upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart")
fun uploadFileMultipart(
    @Part metadata: MultipartBody.Part,
    @Part fileMedia: MultipartBody.Part
): Completable
```

by sending this two Multiparts you get automatically those *--foo_bar_baz* marks from documentation

*"Identify each part with a boundary string, preceded by two hyphens. In addition, add two hyphens after the final boundary string."*