# How to create a txtfile using a string and uploading it to Google Drive

Tags: java, android, google-drive-android-api

I am using the google Drive API within an android application and would like to create a txt file and upload that text file to Google Drive.
For example if the string is: "Hello world", it would create a txt file with the given string and upload it to Google Drive.
Is this possible?
Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

This can be done. Create a normal text file.
See this:
[How To Read/Write String From A File In Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376807/how-to-read-write-string-from-a-file-in-android)

Then using API upload it.
See this:
[How to upload a file to Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675689/how-to-upload-a-file-to-google-drive)

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: You can find almost everything I'm writing in this [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started).

First, Have you authorized your app to run the GoogleDrive api?

You need to register it in the [Google API Manager](https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=drive&credential=client_key&pli=1)
and submit your SHA1 key. You can get that key by going to your SDK/bin folder and running the keytool utility with this code:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore /path-to-your-debug.keystore -list -v
```

Now that you have the autorization, it is time to add the google services API to your code. Go to the build.gradle file and add the service:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
}
```

You will have to sync your project again and maybe download some libs.

Finally you can use the API. Create a connection with the Google Drive API:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstance);

GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(Drive.API)
        .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();
}
```

and then connect:

```
 mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

Okay, now you are connected (unless the user refused to connect with his Drive account and you will need to treat that).

Now create your file:

```
DriveFile myFile
```

Do what you want to do with the file and then save it:

```
file.open(mGoogleApiClient, DriveFile.MODE_WRITE_ONLY, null).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {
@Override
public void onResult(DriveContentsResult result) {
    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
        // Handle error
        return;
    }
    DriveContents driveContents = result.getDriveContents();
}
});
```

Hope I could help!