# Uploading a multipart file in Google Drive using retrofit

Tags: android, file-upload, retrofit2, multipart, google-drive-android-api

As per Google Drive API,  format of multipart upload request is:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart         
HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN]
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=foo_bar_baz
Content-Length: [NUMBER_OF_BYTES_IN_ENTIRE_REQUEST_BODY]

--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
  "name": "myObject"
}

--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: image/jpeg

[JPEG_DATA]

--foo_bar_baz--
```

My question is,
How to create this request using retrofit2 ?

Like this:

```
@POST("/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart")
@Multipart
Call<ModelMultipartResponse> sendMultipartUploadReq(@Header("Authorization")String authToken,
@Part MultipartBody.Part metaPart,
@Part MultipartBody.Part dataPart);
```

Comment: did you find the proper way to do that?

Comment: No...  not yet. :(

Comment: I found the solution which you can see here
[REST API v3. MULTIPART UPLOAD example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55265543/5980046)