# How use Google Drive in Android application

Tags: android, google-drive-api

For example I want from my application to send files to account google drive, without leaving the application. How can this be done? Anyone experienced this?

Comment: Do you have any code to start with? Most people are only going to help if you put in some effort first.

Comment: No. I get it. I wanted to get advice on the documentation, because I found nothing. That is where to start.

Comment: Write `google drive android dev` in google and see the result...

Comment: I was looking for, but there is no example of using Google drive in android application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-android-ui) seems like a pretty good example of how to use Google Drive in an Android application.

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164024/android-open-and-save-files-to-from-google-drive-sdk) is a pretty solid answer on SO on dealing with the same problem.