# Send text file to google drive in android

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I want to send a text file to to google drive from android.

Can I have the links for :

**1. Steps to create an google drive app (Means what should i select)**

**2. Jar files required**

**3. Any sample code**

**4. Manifest content**

Google Drive experts help me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Start from the [Quick Start](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android) on Google Android site.

When you are done with all the authentication process, go for [How to upload file to Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads).

Check out below links for more..

- [Google Drive SDK Sample](http://code.google.com/p/google-drive-sdk-samples/)
- [Tutorial 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164024/android-open-and-save-files-to-from-google-drive-sdk)
- [Get the Jars](http://mavenrepo.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/com/google/apis/google-api-services-drive/v2-rev9-1.8.0-beta/)

Here are the steps to create and configure the project

In Eclipse, create a new Android Application Project.

```
- Type "Drive Quickstart" in Application Name.
- Select API 17: Android 4.2 for the Target SDK.
- Select Google APIs (Google Inc.) (API 17) for the Compile With.
- Leave all other fields with the default values and click Next.
- In all other pages, leave all settings with their default values and click Next till you can click Finish to complete the setup wizard.
```

After following above steps you need to add Google Drive client library to the project.

```
- Select Add Google APIs... from the Google Plugin for Eclipse dropdown.
- Select Drive API v2 from the list and click Finish.
```

[image]

At last make sure you have added the Google Play Services library in your projects Build Path.

- Select **Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries** from the Eclipse menu.
  Click Add External JARs.
- Browse to **/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/libs**, select **google-play-services.jar** and click OK.
- In the Order and Export tab, make sure the checkbox by the **google-play-services.jar** file is checked.

You need to add the `android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS` and `android.permission.INTERNET` permissions to the **AndroidManifest.xml** file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

[For more Details](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android#step_3_set_up_the_sample)