# Android Open and Save String to/from Google Drive SDK

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I have read allot about Google drive integration and I want to save STRING into Google drive and also to retrieve, I have used [this](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/connecting-to-google-drive-from-an-android-app) demo but it is giving me errors.
please anyone provide  me demo for my requirement

Comment: What is the errors? post it

Comment: when i import that demo , it is giving me errors, in all the packages, or can you provide any demo to save STRING into Google drive and also to retrieve?

Comment: Go to this: [https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart)

Comment: ok i have read that, but how can i retrieve the data that i saved?

Comment: that only saved the data to drive, is there any code to get that particular data

Comment: Goo to this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164024/android-open-and-save-files-to-from-google-drive-sdk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164024/android-open-and-save-files-to-from-google-drive-sdk)

Comment: hi, i have used the above code and when i run that code it first capture the image and just crates the FOLDER only into my google drive, i does not saving the image into my google drive.

Comment: you added READ and WRITE PERMISSION in manifest.xml?

Comment: yes i have done that , no issue of PERMISSION

Comment: OutputStream outputStream = result.getContents().getOutputStream();
                // Write the bitmap data from it.
                ByteArrayOutputStream bitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bitmapStream);
                try {
                    outputStream.write(bitmapStream.toByteArray());
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Unable to write file contents.");
                }

Comment: this is code in that link you send me, but it does not send the image to google drive it only writes the image to outputStream

Comment: and one more thig i am getting error
Cannot find DriveId. Are you authorized to view this file?

Comment: It has been answered here - [SO 22350825][1]. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350825/cannot-find-driveid-are-you-authorized-to-view-this-file-android-google-drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's clear the confusion here. Your original question refers to a demo that uses the original [RESTful API (aka DriveSDKv2)](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/), where *Simple Plan* mentions a different API, the new [Google Drive Android API (GDAA)](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started).

The *GDAA*, does not have the full functionality at the moment, but it can be combined with the *DriveSDKv2* to supplement what's missing (delete, description, indexable, ...). On the other hand, the GDAA takes care of all synchronization, offline and caching issues. You just create, retrieve, update the files as if they were local and the magic of up/down synchronization is left to GDAA. And the missing functionality is promised soon.

If you decide to dive into GDAA, there are 3 demos available on Github at the moment:

1. [quick start](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart)
2. [full-blown demo](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos)
3. [trivial example with wrapper class](https://github.com/seanpjanson/140201-GDAA) to create, retrieve files/folders

Both *demo* and *trivial* examples have the *create* functionality with a text written to a file. If you pull any of them and step through, you'll get the idea.