# Store data from android app to my google drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am developing app with simple form information. i would like to get this all information in `my google drive`. User dont need to login with google services. How can i achieve this scenario? I have checked [link1](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/package-summary.html) ,[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164024/android-open-and-save-files-to-from-google-drive-sdk). But m not getting it. How can i store my fields like name, number, address into my drive or some SQL on `My drive account` using api or Drive SDK or library ? I dont want to use any AppEngine. Can anyone guide me, i would highly appreciate.

Comment: wait for Google to integrate Firebase :-)

Answer (score 0):

The Google Drive Android API would do the job for you. It is available via Google Play Services. You can have a look here to see how to save application data.

https://developers.google.com/drive/android/appfolder

Comment: I doubt that GDAA would do the job the OP is asking

Comment: checked this link. but it needs to be signin with googleplus in application. Also i need that information in my account drive.