# How to open Google drive and pick file in android device

Tags: android, file, google-drive-api

In my android application have button called Upload whenever i click the button it needs to redirect to Google Drive, from that i have to pick a file & need read the file (file may be csv),

is there anyway to do??
I have tried below code but it shows Client must connected error

```
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Drive.API).addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                    .addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();

            mGoogleApiClient.connect();

            // Launch user interface and allow user to select file
            IntentSender i = Drive.DriveApi.newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
                    .setMimeType(new String[] { "text/plain" })
                    .build(mGoogleApiClient);
            try {
                startIntentSenderForResult(i, 100, null, 0, 0, 0);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164024/android-open-and-save-files-to-from-google-drive-sdk

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ACTION_PICK will do the trick.

For example if you were to pick contacts,

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);

would list your contacts from Drive,Phone Book etc.

Comment: whats the package name for drive to open??

Comment: You dont need to give a package name. Open an intent with the ACTION_PICK and you can set the datatype to be */*

Comment: check it out my updated question, that's how i tried to open an drive