# How to upload a file to GoogleDrive in android

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I refer from this code

```
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(activity);
am.getAuthToken(am.getAccounts())[0],
    "oauth2:" + DriveScopes.DRIVE,
    new Bundle(),
    true,
    new OnTokenAcquired(),
    null);


private class OnTokenAcquired implements AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> {
    @Override
    public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> result) {
        try {
            final String token = result.getResult().getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
            HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
            JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
            Drive.Builder b = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null);
            b.setJsonHttpRequestInitializer(new JsonHttpRequestInitializer() {
                @Override
                public void initialize(JSonHttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                    DriveRequest driveRequest = (DriveRequest) request;
                    driveRequest.setPrettyPrint(true);
                    driveRequest.setKey(CLIENT ID YOU GOT WHEN SETTING UP THE CONSOLE BEFORE YOU STARTED CODING)
                    driveRequest.setOauthToken(token);
                }
            });

            final Drive drive = b.build();

            final com.google.api.services.drive.model.File body = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
            body.setTitle("My Test File");
    body.setDescription("A Test File");
    body.setMimeType("text/plain");

            final FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/plain", an ordinary java.io.File you'd like to upload. Make it using a FileWriter or something, that's really outside the scope of this answer.)
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file = drive.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
                        alreadyTriedAgain = false; // Global boolean to make sure you don't repeatedly try too many times when the server is down or your code is faulty... they'll block requests until the next day if you make 10 bad requests, I found.
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        if (!alreadyTriedAgain) {
                            alreadyTriedAgain = true;
                            AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(activity);
                            am.invalidateAuthToken(am.getAccounts()[0].type, null); // Requires the permissions MANAGE_ACCOUNTS & USE_CREDENTIALS in the Manifest
                            am.getAuthToken (same as before...)
                        } else {
                            // Give up. Crash or log an error or whatever you want.
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start();
            Intent launch = (Intent)result.getResult().get(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);
            if (launch != null) {
                startActivityForResult(launch, 3025);
                return; // Not sure why... I wrote it here for some reason. Might not actually be necessary.
            }
        } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
            // Handle it...
        } catch (AuthenticatorException e) {
            // Handle it...
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Handle it...
        }
    }
}
```

In jsonHttpRequestInitializer i get an issues. [GoogleClient$Builder cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files] please suggest me what i have to do...

Comment: Check if you have the latest library

Comment: Since you are on Android, use the Drive Android API. You can see a sample for creating/uploading a file here: https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/src/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/CreateFileActivity.java

Answer (score 2):

You have two different APIs you can use on Android, the [REST](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/) and the [GDAA](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started).

REST is the 'barebones' API that gives you the full functionality of Google Drive. You also have an interactive playground to test everything (see [the bottom of this page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list)). But you have to manage the network delays, failures, etc... yourself. Ideally you would delegate that work to sync adapter service.

GDAA is built on top of REST, resides in Google Play Services and behaves as a local API with delayed promotion of objects (folders/files) to the Drive. Has only limited functionality compared to REST (forget thumbnail link, etc...). Essentially, you talk to GDAA and GDAA talks to the Drive on it's own schedule. So, you don't have to worry about on-line / off-line situations. Be careful though, this may also cause synchronization issues, since you don't have direct control over object promotion timing. The demos for GDAA can be found [here](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart) and [here](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos).

I've also created a simple [CRUD demo app](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo) that you can step through. The upload you're asking resides in create() method there. It is not fully up-to-date, since GDAA has implemented the 'trash' functionality already (in Google Play Services 7.00 / Rev. 23).

Good Luck