# Connect with Google Drive without add account to android.accounts.AccountManager?

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-drive-api

please tell me whether it is possible?
I will connect to google drive, but I do not want to add an account to android AccountManager.

```
        credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
            activity, Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
            .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff())
            .setSelectedAccountName(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME);
```

It does not work because my account is not added to android.accounts.AccountManager.

I do not want to show the user with which account the application is connected and where taking files.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot connect to google Drive with out adding your account to Account manager. It acts like Authentication, from where you will get the token to access the users data. You can check these links http://blog.tomtasche.at/2013/05/google-oauth-on-android-using.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164024/android-open-and-save-files-to-from-google-drive-sdk/12321331#12321331 which has information about account manager and how to add your accounts.

Comment: I have the same problem. I want to use the google drive and not to add the account to the device. Have you found any solution for this?