# Android: Upload all types of file on Google Drive

Tags: android, android-studio, upload, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload file on google drive from the picker, I refered https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart it's working good but it's only uploaded image instead I want to upload number of types file like text,apk,image etc. So how can upload it? Can any one help!!!

Comment: you are from pune?

Comment: No, Can you help to solve this problem?

Comment: the link you have mentioned not working for all the file types ??

Comment: No, it's only working for image

Comment: As i can see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164024/android-open-and-save-files-to-from-google-drive-sdk they are providing number of libraries ,you can try it

Comment: you can check this link https://developers.google.com/drive/android/

Comment: I had seen it but I don't know how can i use it

Comment: You can check samples.check this full code https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/CreateFileWithCreatorActivity.java

Comment: you will also need this code to complete your code use this two files to code https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/BaseDemoActivity.java

Comment: gudluck komal !! if not done,mail it to me at sr.amitranjan@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks it works for me!!!

Comment: Welcome.Glad it help you.