# how to let user write/read files in my google drive?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I'm developing one android app.
I keep some data for this app in my google drive.
Is it possible when user run this app to read/write the data file that in my google drive? how to achieve it?

Comment: try this https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart

Comment: its a bad idea, your app will fail once it has a few users plus you risk an easy hack into your drive.. how-to is explained in the api docs. try it and show us the code that wont work.

Comment: I also think that's a bad idea, firebase might be more appropriate: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/

Comment: A Service Account is the best way to proceed

Comment: perhaps a gmail just for the purpose of this app? if you need it linked to your account, you could make a shared folder that you could add files to, the second account would be able to access and let the app edit it.

Comment: It would be better to use a google cloud storage [bucket,](https://cloud.google.com/storage) those start at $0.01(USD.) and you get a $300 credit for signing up for google cloud storage, which comes with a bunch of goodies for developers and google app scripts users

Answer (score 0):

Read the instruction here,all about write and read data https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro

Comment: I can find the instruction about how to read/write files of user owns google drive account. but I do not find how to let app user read/write files of my own google drive.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below link which contain the code and the detail about the implementation :

[Android Open and Save files to/from Google Drive SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164024/android-open-and-save-files-to-from-google-drive-sdk)