# How to download publicly shared file from Google Drive using REST API

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-oauth

Is there any way to download publically shared file from Google Drive using REST API in Android? the official documentation page [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads) says to do

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0B9jNhSvVjoIVM3dKcGRKRmVIOVU?alt=media
Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

Where actually can I get the ACCESS_TOKEN? I authenticated my account by following the quick start guide [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/android) and generated `credentials.xml` file

I want to download a shared file in my app, which i think would not require user authentication, if there is any way to do this without asking user for sign-in using `GoogleSingInOption.Builder` let me know by answering this question

i have checked similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164024/android-open-and-save-files-to-from-google-drive-sdk) like this, but they all show solution for downloading or uploading files from users personal drive space by authenticating user

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164024/android-open-and-save-files-to-from-google-drive-sdk/54394625

Answer (score 0):

If you just scrolled down a bit on that page, you'd see that if you authenticate with google you can just use their api to make the request for you.

```
String fileId = "0B9jNhSvVjoIVM3dKcGRKRmVIOVU";
OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
driveService.files().get(fileId)
    .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

Comment: I wanted to try that, but what's driveService?

Comment: I think that is referring to this class https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Drive_1_1v3_1_1DriveService.html

Comment: I was wrong, in the quickstart guide the function getDriveService() is created and ran, i tkink driveService is referring to that object (class com.google.api.services.drive.Drive)

Comment: Hmm... so do you have any idea on how to get it done?

Comment: Drive driveService = getDriveService();

Comment: i think this answers your question better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164024/android-open-and-save-files-to-from-google-drive-sdk