# How to connect google drive with static username and password in android?

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

i want to connect my google drive with static username and password in my application. 
After connecting i want to download file from google drive.
So any other person can download files from my google drive account.

i read this link but don't understood where to pass username and password.
[Android Open and Save files to/from Google Drive SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164024/android-open-and-save-files-to-from-google-drive-sdk)

Comment: Welcome to Stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Then come back edit your question add any links from your research into your problem. Any code you are using to try to achieve this as well as any issues you are having with your current solution.

Comment: **Note** Using username and password to access a Google account is called client login. Google discontinued that end point in 2015. You will not be logging into a user account with login and password.  You probably need something like a service account I am not an android dev so cant tell you if that is supported with android.