# Can I SignIn in google account inside my android application code?

Tags: android, google-account

I am new in andoid developement and not fluent in english, sorry for mistake.

In my first android application I want to send my log files to my GoogleDrive, I am already can SignIn using

`startActivityForResult(client.getSignInIntent(), REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN);`

as was shown in Google exemple and upload my file in selectad google account, but I don't need users account, I need signin using my Google account i.e. inside code, but I don't understand how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to integrate G Suite apis for this. You should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12164024/4723045) as well.