# Upload files from android to google drive folder

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-platform, sdk, google-drive-api

I have created an android application that allows the users to do a test and save the results in a local .xlsl file. This app will run on around 30 devices. Since it is part of a scientific research I need it to automatically save the xlsl file in a specific folder on google drive which I do not own (but which they gave me access permissions and I can write/read). I'm reading the tutorial on the [google docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java), but from what I understood I need to sign up on all the devices with the account I used for the authentication. Are there ways to avoid it? The devices will probably be without any account on it and since I don't need to know who's uploading it and would be fine to pre-insert my credential in the code so it will automatically upload it with them. Is it possible?

Comment: you can create one token and save it in the app and use only that token, this will allow everyone to update that target with same credentials. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12321331/175554 may help more