# Bug: files uploaded via desktop or web client have hidden tag when listed via API

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

Files uploaded to Google Drive sometimes incorrectly have a hidden tag when listed via the Document List v3 REST API:

```
<category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005/labels' term='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005/labels#hidden' label='hidden'/>
```

This happens if:

- a subfolder is created via the Google Drive desktop client and files are copied in, or
- a folder is uploaded via the Google Drive web client.

The folder does not have the hidden tag, but the files that were uploaded do.

The files do not have this tag if:

- they are *individually* uploaded via the Google Drive web client to the subfolder, or
- they are uploaded *via the REST API* to the subfolder, or
- they are uploaded via the desktop client to the My Drive *root*.

The files and folders show up in Google Drive whether they have the hidden tag or not.

We're using the API with the following scope:

```
https://docs.google.com/feeds/ https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/ https://docs.googleusercontent.com/
```

I have verified and can recreate this with the OAuth 2.0 playground.

Google Drive desktop client version 1.3.3209.2600 on Win7 32-bit

I guess these must be bugs in the API...

Comment: We're using the following URL to list the contents of the folder:
https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/{folderid}/contents

Answer (score 1):

Hidden behavior is different between the UI and the API. It merely implies whether a file is listed in the root directory. You should probably ignore this field.

Also, since the Documents List API is deprecated, you should use the Drive API instead.

Comment: This was never the case with Google Docs, so in my view it is a bug. As for deprecation: the Document List API  has been deprecated for a week now. You'll understand that migrating an extensive existing codebase to a new API takes a lot more time than that.

Comment: Is the Drive API working yet? When I checked this morning I found that I still couldn't download files using it. The Google Play Services, the launch of which I've been told will fix the Drive APIs, remains unreleased or at least the page for it hasn't been updated since its release. See what I'm talking about here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521883/unable-to-download-file-created-by-my-app-on-google-drive-but-can-get-the-metad